# Unable to access Azure Virtual Machine from 3389 port restricted network

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, remote-desktop

I am facing a strange issue of not able to access Azure Virtual Machine from the Work Network. Whereas I am able to access the VM from my Home Network. Seems like there is some sort of firewall policy conflicts which can't be modified. As port 3389 is restricted by most of the network firewall, I have thought of changing the RDP accessibility port from 3389 to 443. As HTTPs would be allowed by most of the Network Firewalls. I have followed the steps provided in the below link, but still I am unable to access. Please help me how I can troubleshoot this issue

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure/Port-Mapping-on-new-Azure-Portal/td-p/63181

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I am able to resolve the issue and able to access the RDP from work network. Below are steps which were performed

1. Created Network Load Balancer & Added NAT rules for 443 port -> https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure/Port-Mapping-on-new-Azure-Portal/td-p/63181
2. Update the Network Security Group -> Change the inbound port rules from 3389 to 443
3. If Possible disable the windows firewall on the Azure VM or Add inbound rules to open 443 port -> https://windowscentral.com/how-open-port-windows-firewall
4. Update the registry key update the port number from 3389 to 443 -> http://www.itprotoday.com/management-mobility/using-rdp-access-servers-over-internet

Thats it, VM is accessible like a charm

Answer (score 1):

I think that this issue should be caused by the [source from your Organization intranet edge device](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/detailed-troubleshoot-rdp?toc=%2Fazure%2Fvirtual-machines%2Fwindows%2Ftoc.json#source-2-organization-intranet-edge-device).

> ## Check your organization intranet edge device for:
>
> **>An internal firewall blocking HTTPS connections to the Internet.**
>
> **>A proxy server preventing Remote Desktop connections.**
>
> **>Intrusion detection or network monitoring software running on devices in your edge network that is preventing Remote Desktop
> connections.**
>
> Work with your network administrator to correct the settings of your
> organization intranet edge device to allow HTTPS-based Remote Desktop
> connections to the Internet.

[image]

Please let me know if it helps!

Comment: Thanks, I do have I more question. After I have added NAT rule for 443, should the RDP accessible on 443 port? I have changed the RDP connection from 3389 to 443 but I am unable to connect to server even from home network. Does this mean that there is some issue in the setting?

Comment: @suryakiran  That makes scense. I think this changed settings may be the cause.

Comment: @suryakiran . Try to use another port which is allowed in your Work network And remmenber to also allowed this port in Azure NSG and VM firewall.

Comment: How allow the port in VM firewall?

Comment: @suryakiran https://www.windowscentral.com/how-open-port-windows-firewall

Comment: I have disabled the firewall on the VM. Also open 443 on Azure Network Security Group of that VM. Still no luck :(

Comment: @As I said in the answer. It may caused by your organazation Network devices. You need to check this first.